# Google Apps Script trigger success

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script trigger that runs every Tuesday at a certain time.

Google allows for notifications if the trigger fails for some reason, is there any way that I can receive some sort of email/notification if the trigger runs successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `MailApp.sendMail()` call inside the function that sends an email notification to you when the trigger is successful.

Alternatively, you can use the `console.log()` statement inside the function and the activity will be recorded in the StackDriver logs.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and works very well, thanks.

Comment: If the answer resolves your problem, consider accepting it.